# Eloquent request after login page

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a strange issue with Eloquent.

I have an AdminController with an index method and $admin is taking the id of the connected Admin ...

```
public function index() {
    $admin = Admin::findOrFail(Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id);
    return view('admin.home', compact('admin') );
}
```

I defined the relationship in the Admin model :

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
                   ->withPivot('created_at','updated_at', 'deleted_at');
}
```

In my view i add this foreach :

```
@foreach($admin->users as $user)
    {{ $user->name}} {{ $user->surname }} <br>
@endforeach
```

As  a result i should see users in a simple list ... But i have : 
Undefined variable: admin

If i change the return view in the index method the list is correctly displayed. As the admin/home is the landing page after login i wonder if the issue is here ... I tried to find where i defined the route to this page unsuccessfully. I also use Hesto/Multiauth

Thanks for your help

Here is my error message : 
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: admin (View: C:\wamp\www\fondamentaux-dev\resources\views\admin\home.blade.php)

This part is highlighted :

users; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $user): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>

Comment: please add your full error message with full view code

Comment: what is your view name where you have used `@foreach($admin->users as $user)` ?

Comment: I used it in admin.home view and i don't have any results and admin.home2 where i see results

Comment: add your full home.blade.php please

Comment: Btw: `Auth::guard('admin')->user()` is enough, I believe you don't need to refetch it.

Comment: i tried using : Auth::guard('admin')->user() with refetching it but it gives an error message ... Concerning the whole page i don't think i could put everything here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found out an answer which satisfies me ... 
I think i had conflict with middleware so i modified the LoginController (Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/LoginController) and changed the redirection URL ...

I had :

```
public $redirectTo = '/admin/home';
```

I changed it into :

```
public $redirectTo = '/admin/welcome';
```